# Android SDK is Unavailable

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-studio-3.0, android-sdk-2.3

Can someone help me? I've reinstalled my Android Studio several times, but I always encounter the "ANDROID SDK Unavailable" issue. I followed the instructions to disable the firewall, but it didn't resolve the issue. For your information, I am not using a VPN. I tried downloading an old version, specifically Giraffe 2022 Canary 1, but I still face the same problem with the SDK. Thank you to anyone who can assist.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QlTJ.png)

resolve my problem. :(

Comment: What is your OS? Are you in a corporate environment (with intercepting proxy) or any other special type of internet connection?